# How difficult would it be to find valid answers for this hash arrangement?

Tags: cryptography, hash-function, quantum-computation

If $A$ is a 160-bit number, and $X \& Y$ are two SHA-1 hashes, to be generated such that the 320-bit number $X\mathbin\|A$ hashed to $Y$, and the 320-bit number $A \mathbin\| Y$ hashed to $X$?

How hard is it to find pairs of values of $X\&Y$ that would fulfill the above criteria? How many valid pairs of $X \& Y$ would one expect to find for an arbitrary value of $A$?

Comment: Your question is not clear. You can use `\mathbin\|` $\mathbin\|$ for concatenation  in $LaTeX$ mode

Comment: Thanks, is that better?

Comment: I don't see the benefit of this question apart from enthusiasm or curiosity.  So you want $Y = \text{Hash}(X\mathbin\| A)$ and $X = \text{Hash}(A\mathbin\| Y)$

Comment: See, https://shattered.io/

Comment: "So you want Y=Hash(X∥A) and X=Hash(A∥Y)" Yes, that's what I'm interested in, for SHA-1.

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in attack for SHA-1, the best-known attack on SHA-1 is [SHAttered](https://shattered.io/).

[SHAttered paper](https://shattered.io/static/shattered.pdf) is  an *identical-prefix collision attack*, where a given prefix $p$ is extended with two distinct *near-collision block pairs* such that they collide for any suffix S:

Specifically, the attack takes a prefix $p$ and finds two pairs of message blocks $(m_0, m_1) \ne (m'_0, m'_1)$ such that $$\operatorname{SHA-1}(p \mathbin\Vert m_0 \mathbin\Vert m_1 \mathbin\Vert s) = \operatorname{SHA-1}(p \mathbin\Vert m'_0 \mathbin\Vert m'_1 \mathbin\Vert s)$$ for any suffix $s$.

> The computational effort spent on our attack is estimated to be equivalent to $2^{63.1}$ SHA-1 calls

Also, a recent article might interest you;

- [From Collisions to Chosen-Prefix Collisions  Application to Full SHA-1](https://eprint.iacr.org/2019/459.pdf)

We might close to signature forgeries.

Comment: Thanks, It's not so much that I'm interested in an attack [although it is interesting stuff], rather how hard it would be to find pairs of hashes where each one relies on the value of the other, as well as the hashed value.

Comment: That is quite a huge research problem, IMHO. Normally finding a collision is $\sqrt{n}$ due to birthday attack. However, you want really a specific attack. In a collision attack, we are not controlling the output. That is why the attack on SHA-1 is important.